# How old is Sugar?

Tags: one-piece

It is said that the Hobi Hobi no Mi grants eternal youth to the user, besides allowing them to turn people into toys and wiping their existence out of anyone else's mind.

So that being said, it is implied that Sugar is much older than she really is, and that the Hobi Hobi no Mi only makes her look young. But I have tried looking at the chapters she is in but there is no mention of how old she is.

Is there something out there that tells us how old Sugar is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this [wiki page](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Sugar) her age is mentioned. Due to Hobi Hobi no Mi she has two age which are **10(biologically)** and **22(legally)**. So she looks like 10 year old but she is actually 22 years old.

> Sugar ate the Hobi Hobi no Mi at age **10**, ceasing to age since then.
>
> It is said that the user stops aging once the fruit has been eaten, as she remains a 10-years old despite being chronologically **22**. This also happens with her victims, as Kyros, who was a toy during **10** years, when reverting to normal did not show any biological signs of aging

[image: Sugar 10 year old]
[image: Sugar 22 year old]

Comment: The part about Kyros is interesting. Would that mean, Sugar actually lengthened the toys' lives?

Comment: @PeterRaeves I can't confirm that, but in a sense yes, if your body does not show any biological sign of aging you are more prone to live longer, i think it does not make you immortal, you may die in toy form.